# Is the closure $\overline{ \{X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} : \rho(M-NX) < 1\} }$ equal to $ \{X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} : \rho(M-NX) \le 1\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, spectral-radius

Suppose $M \in \mathcal M(n \times n; \mathbb R)$ and $N \in \mathcal M(n \times m; \mathbb R)$ are fixed with $N \neq 0$. Let
\begin{align*}
  E =  \{X \in \mathcal{M}(m \times n; \mathbb R) : \rho(M-NX) < 1\},
\end{align*}
where $\rho(\cdot)$ denotes the spectral radius of a matrix.
I want to know whether the closure $\bar{E}$ of $E$ is equal to
$$F = \{X \in \mathcal{M}(m \times n; \mathbb R) : \rho(M-NX) \le 1\}.$$
**We will assume $E$ is not empty.**

If we define following composition of continuous maps
\begin{align*}
f: X \mapsto M-NX \mapsto (\lambda_1(M-NX), \dots, \lambda_n(M-NX)) \mapsto (|\lambda_1(M-NX)|, \dots, |\lambda_n(M-NX)|)  \\
\mapsto \max( |\lambda_1(M-NX)|, \dots, |\lambda_n(M-NX)|).
\end{align*}
Then $f$ is continuous into $[0, \infty)$. We note $E = \{X: f^{-1}([0,1)\}$ and $F = \{X: f^{-1}([0,1])\}$. So $E$ is open and $F$ is closed. Clearly $\bar{E} \subset F$. But I could not show the other direction (or possibly $\bar{E}$ is a proper subset of $F$). I tried to construct a sequence $\{X_n\}$ converging to $X \in F \setminus E$ by multiplying a factor $1-\varepsilon$ to $X$ but apparently to conclude $\bar{E} = F$ we need some kind of sublinearatily of spectral radius which is not true in general.

Comment: If $N=0$ and $\rho(M)=1$, then the LHS is empty but the RHS is the whole matrix space.

Comment: Actually I made the assumption $E$ is not empty. But sorry, the assumption was in the middle which made it not clear enough.

Comment: The problem can be restated as follows: "if $1$ is a local minimum of $f$, must it also be a global minimum?" That is certainly true if $N$ has rank $m$, as then the mapping $X \mapsto M - NX$ is open and any local minimum of $f$ must be a local minimum of $\rho$, which can only be $0$. For lower ranks the answer is less obvious.

Comment: @NielsJ.Diepeveen: I don't quite understand your restated version. If it is true, i.e., $1$ is a global minimum, then $E = \emptyset$ and it is certainly true $\bar{E} \neq F$. But I am assuming $E$ is not empty (this can be done by choosing appropriate $M,N$).

Comment: @NielsJ.Diepeveen: Thinking about the second part of your comment, I can see $X \mapsto M-NX$ is open if $N$ has full rank, but could not follow why the local minimum of $f$ must be a local minimum of $\rho(\cdot)$. Sorry, I am having too many questions.

Comment: Put $g(X) = M - NX$ and suppose $g$ is open. If $y$ is a local minimum of $\rho \circ g$, there is a $X_1 \in \mathcal{M}(m \times n; \mathbb{R})$ and a neighbourhood $U$ of $X_1$ such that $\rho(g(X_1)) = \min \rho[g[U]] = y$. Since $g$ is open, $g[U]$ is a neighbourhood of $g(X_1)$, hence $g(X_1)$ is a local minimizer of $\rho$ and $y$ is a local minimum.

Comment: In the restatement, I ignored the case that $f$ never takes the value $1$, because it is trivial. With that exception, the condition $E = \emptyset$ is equivalent to $1$ being a global minimum of $f$. The condition $F\setminus\overline{E} \ne \emptyset$ is equivalent to $1$ being a local minimum of $f$. Hence, my restatement is essentially the contrapositive of $E \ne \emptyset \implies F\setminus\overline{E} = \emptyset$, which is what you were trying to prove.

Comment: @NielsJ.Diepeveen: See the point. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\NN}{{\mathbb{N}}}\newcommand{\CC}{{\mathbb{C}}}\newcommand{\RR}{{\mathbb{R}}}\newcommand{\QQ}{{\mathbb Q}}\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\left(\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}\right)}\newcommand{\lam}{\lambda}\renewcommand{\P}{{\mathcal P}}\newcommand{\N}{{\mathcal N}}\newcommand{\M}{{\mathcal M}}\renewcommand{\L}{{\mathcal L}}
\newcommand{\EQ}[2]{\begin{equation} {{#2}\label{#1}} \end{equation}}$

Claim: The closure of $E$ is equal to $F.$

Proof: In a first step, we normalise the problem.
We can assume that $N$ is a block matrix
$$N=\mat{I_r&0\\0&0},$$
where $r$ is the rank of $N$, $I_r$ is the identity of size $r\leq\min(m,n)$ and
the other blocks consist of zeros and
have appropriate sizes ( $r\times (m-r)$, $(n-r)\times r$ and $(n-r)\times (m-r)$). Some or
even all of them can be absent. To justify this recall that any $n$ by $m$ matrix
$N$ can be written
$$N=U\mat{I_r&0\\0&0}V,\ \ r=\mbox{rank}(N),$$
where $U$ and $V$ are invertible. Then the condition $\rho(M-NX)<1$ can be written
$$\rho\left(U^{-1}MU-\mat{I_r&0\\0&0}(VXU)\right)<1,$$
because similar matrices have the same spectrum.
Then we can assume that $r=m$ since the zero block column of $N$ (and the correponding rows of $X$)
do not contribute anything. Finally we can assume that the first $m$ rows of $M$ contains only zeros:
Otherwise, we modify $X$ and $M$ accordingly.

From now on, we assume without loss of generality that $N=\mat{I_m\\0}$
and the first $m$ rows of $M$ vanish.

We first consider the case $m=1.$ This will also be useful as a preparation for the general case.
We use the [Laplace (or cofactor) expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion)
for the first row of the determinant giving the characteristic polynomial $p_{M-NX}(\lam)$
$$\tag{1}\label{lap}{\det(\lam I - M+ NX)=(x_1+\lam)C_1(\lam)+\sum_{k=2}^n x_kC_k(\lam)}$$
where $X=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $C_j(\lam)$, $j=1,\dots,n$ are the $1,j$ cofactors of $\lam I - M$, that is
$C_j(\lam)=(-1)^{j+1}M_{1j}(\lam)$, where $M_{1j}(\lam)$ is the determinant of the $n-1$ by $n-1$
matrix obtained from $\lam I-M$ by deleting its first row and its $j$-th column.
Observe that $C_1(\lam)\in \lam^{n-1}+\P_{n-1}$ and $C_j(\lam)\in\P_{n-1}$, where $\P_k$ denotes the
vector space of all polynomials of degree less than $k$.
Before continuing the proof, we need some auxiliary statements.

**Lemma 1** Let $D(\lam)$ denote the gcd of $C_j(\lam)$, $j=1,\dots,n$ and let $d$ denote its
degree. Then the mapping $
\EQ{map}{L:\RR^{ n} \to D(\lam)\P_{n-d},\ \  L(X)=\sum_{k=1}^n x_kC_k(\lam)\mbox{ if } X=(x_1,\dots,x_n)}$
is surjective (or onto).

Remark: The characteristic polynomial of $M-NX$ is the given by $\lam C_1(\lam)+L(X)$.

Proof: Observe first that each $L(X)$ must be divisible by $D(\lam)$ because every $C_j(\lam)$
is divisible by it. Consider now a polynomial $p(\lam)\in\P_{n-d}$. We want to find $X\in\RR^n$
such that $L(X)=D(\lam)p(\lam)$.

Consider the polynomials $B_j(\lam)=C_j(\lam)/D(\lam)$. By assumption, their gcd is 1. So by
Bezout's identity,  $p$ can be expressed in the form
$$p(\lam)=\sum_{j=1}^ng_j(\lam)B_j(\lam),$$
where $g_j(\lam)$ are certain polynomials. The Lemma is proved once we show the

Claim: It is possible  to choose constant $g_j(\lam)$.

If $\ell$ denotes the maximum of the degrees of $g_j(\lam)$, $j=2,\dots,n$, then we have to show that
we can achieve $\ell=0$. Indeed, then $\sum_{j=2}^ng_jB_j(\lam)$ is in $\P_{n-1-d}$ and as
$B_1(\lam)\in \lam^{n-d-1}+\P_{n-d-1}$, the quotient
$g_1(\lam)=(p(\lam)-\sum_{j=2}^ng_jB_j(\lam))/B_1(\lam)$
must also be a constant.

Suppose, we could not achieve $\ell=0$ and that a certain $\ell>0$ is the minimal $\ell$ possible.
Then we write $g_j(\lam)=h_{j\ell}\lam^\ell\mod\P_{\ell}$ for $j=2,\dots,n$.
Now let $z_k(\lam)$ denote the $k$-th row of $\lam I-M$ for $k=2,\dots,n$.
Its components $z_{k,j}(\lam)$ are constant except for
the $k$-th one, which is $z_{kk}(\lam)=\lam-m_{kk}$ with a diagonal element of $M$. Finally define
$\tilde M(\lam)=\lam I -M -\lam E_{11}$, where $E_{11}$ is the matrix having a 1 in the upper left
position and zeros elsewhere.
The determinant of $\tilde M(\lam)- N\,z_k(\lam)$ is zero, because the first and the $k$-th row  of
the matrix are identical. This means that
$$0=\sum_{j=1}^n z_{kj}(\lam)C_j(\lam)=D(\lam)\left(\sum_{j=1}^nz_{kj}(\lam)B_j(\lam)\right).$$
for $k=2,\dots,n$. Therefore we also have
$$p(\lam)=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(g_j(\lam)-\sum_{k=2}^nh_{k\ell}z_{kj}(\lam)\lam^{\ell-1}\right)
   \,B_j(\lam).$$
By construction, the factors of $B_2,\dots,B_n$ have a degree smaller than $\ell$ contradicting
the assumed minimality of $\ell$. Therefore we can achieve constant $g_2,\dots,g_n$ and
as seen above, the Lemma is proved.

**Corollary 1** Let $D(\lam)$ denote the gcd of $C_j(\lam)$, $j=1,\dots,n$ and let $d$ denote its
degree. Then the kernel $K$ of the mapping $L$ of Lemma 1 has dimension $d$ and there is a
$(n-d)$-dimensional subspace $S$ of $\RR^n$ such that the restriction
$L{\big|}_S:S\to D(\lam)\P_{n-d}$ of $L$ is bijective (or one to one and onto).

Proof: The first statement follows from the rank-nullity theorem and the sujectivity of $L$:
$\dim K+\dim \P_{n-d}=n$.

For the second, we consider the unit vectors
$e_j=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)$ with a $1$ at the $j$-th position and their images $L(e_j)$, $j=1,\dots,n$.
They generate the image of $D(\lam)\P_{n-d}$ of $L$ which has dimension $n-d$. Therefore we can select
a basis $\{L(e_j)\}_{j\in\M}$ among them, where $\M$ is a certain subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with $n-d$
elements. Then we put $S=\langle\{e_j\}_{j\in\M}\rangle$. Clearly $L{\big|}_S:S\to \mbox{im}(L)$ is an
isomorphism.

For later use, we select $d$ vectors generating $K$, namely the vectors
$z_r=e_r-\left(L{\big|_S}\right)^{-1}L(e_r)$, $r\in\N:=\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus \M$.

After these preliminaries, let us now continue the proof of the claim in the case $m=1$.
First, we show that the gcd $D(\lam)$ of the $C_j(\lam)$ has only zeros inside the open unit disk,
that is $|\mu|<1$ for any zero $\mu$ of $D$. This comes from the assumption that there exists a
matrix $X_0\in E$, i.e.\ such that the spectral radius $\rho(M-N\,X_0)<1$ and the expansion
of the characteristic polynomial (see below Lemma 1)
$$p_{M-N X_0}(\lam)=\lam C_1(\lam)+L(X_0).$$
Since $D(\lam)$ divides $C_1(\lam)$ and $L(X_0)$, it is a factor of $p_{M-N X_0}(\lam)$, which has
only zeros in the open unit disk. So the same holds for $D(\lam)$.

Now let any $X_1\in F$ be given, i.e.\ the characteristic polynomial
$p_{M-N X_1}(\lam)=\lam C_1(\lam)+L(X_1)$ has all its zeros in the closed unit disk,
i.e.\ $|\mu|\leq 1$ if $\mu$ is a zero of $p_{M-N X_1}(\lam)$.
We want to find $X\in E$ (i.e.\ with $\rho(M-NX)<1$) arbitrarily close to $X_1$.

Consider the quotient $q_1(\lam)=p_{M-N X_1}(\lam)/D(\lam)$. Observe that the zeros
of $q_1(\lam)$ are in the closed unit disk and that all the zeros of $p_{M-N X_1}(\lam)$
having modulus 1 must be zeros of $q_1$, because $D(\lam)$ has no such zeros.
Let us write $q_1(\lam)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-d}(\lam-\mu_k)$ with certain $\mu_k$, $|\mu_k|\leq1$.
Now define for $s\in[0,1[$ the polynomials $q_s(\lam)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-d}(\lam-s\mu_k)$.
Their coefficients are real because, as for $q_1(\lam)$, its non-real zeros appear in pairs
of conjugate complex numbers. By construction, the zeros of $q_s$ are in the open unit disk.

Recall that $L(X_1)=p_{M-N X_1}(\lam)-\lam C_1(\lam)=q_1(\lam)D(\lam)-\lam C_1(\lam)
=:p_1(\lam)$. Therefore
$X_1-\left(L\big|_S\right)^{-1}p_1(\lam)=:Z_1$ is an element of the kernel $K$ of
$L$. Now put $p_s(\lam)=q_s(\lam)D(\lam)-\lam C_1(\lam)$ and
$$X_s=Z_1+\left(L\big|_S\right)^{-1}p_s(\lam)$$
for $s\in[0,1[$.

Then as $s\to1-$, we first have $q_s(\lam)\to q_1(\lam)$, next $p_s(\lam)\to p_1(\lam)$
and then by the continuity of
$\left(L\big|_S\right)^{-1}$, we have $X_s\to X_1$.
As by construction the characteristic polynomials of $M-NX_s$ are $q_s(\lam)D(\lam)$,
we have constructed $X_s\in E$, $s\in[0,1[$, tending to the given $X_1$.
This completes the proof in the case $m=1$.

For arbitrary $m$, the proof is identical if the gcd $D(\lam)$ of the cofactors
$C_j(\lam),\, j=1,\dots,n$ has all its zeros in the open unit disk.
Actually, except for the partitioning of the matrix, we are in the case $m=1$.
Unfortunately,
this is not necessarily the case. To repair this, we will modify row by row
of a matrix $X_1\in F$ into rows  of algebraically independent transcendants - of course inside
$F$ and by arbitrarily small amounts. Then we show that $D(\lam)$ has only zeros $\mu$,
$|\mu|<1$ if the rows 2 to $m$ of $X_1$ contain algebraically independent transcendants.

Given $X_1\in\RR^{m,n}$, we denote by $X_1^{(1)}$ its first row and by $\hat X_1$ the matrix in which
the elements of the first row have been replaced by zeros. Then
$$M-NX_1=M-\tilde N\hat X_1-e_1X_1^{(1)},$$
where $\tilde N$ is obtained from $N$ by replacing the upper left element by 0.
Here $e_1$ is the first unit vector in $\RR^n$, later it will also denote the one in $\RR^m$.

**Lemma 2** Given $X_1\in F$ and a positive $\delta$, there exists a row vector $y$ such that
a) $||y-X_1^{(1)}||<\delta,$
b) $\hat X_1+e_1y\in F$, that is $\rho(M-\tilde N \hat X_1-e_1y)\leq1$ and
c) the elements of $y$ are algebraically independent transcendents over the field
$\QQ(M,\hat X_1)$ generated by the elements of $M$ and $\hat X_1$.

Proof: We proceed as in the proof of the case $m=1$. The matrix $\tilde M=M-\tilde N \hat X_1$
plays the role of $M$, the polynomials $C_j(\lam)$, $j=1,\dots,n$, are the $1,j$ cofactors
of $\lam I-\tilde M$ and $D(\lam)$ is their gcd. Lemma 1 and its corollary still hold.
Then the characteristic polynomial
$$p_{M-NX_1}(\lam)=p_{\tilde M-e_1X_1^{(1)}}(\lam)=\lam C_1(\lam)+L(X_1^{(1)})$$
has all its zeros in the closed unit disk and it is a multiple of $D(\lam).$
Therefore $D(\lam)$ has only zeros in the closed unit disk in the present situation.

Again, we consider $p_1(\lam)=p_{M-NX_1}(\lam)-\lam C_1(\lam)=L(X_1^{(1)})$,
$Y_1=\left(L\big|_S\right)^{-1}p_1(\lam)$ and the element
$Z_1=X_1^{(1)}-Y_1$ of the kernel $K$ of $L$. We will now modify $Y_1,Z_1$ a little bit to
obtain the vector $y$ required in the statement.

We begin with $Z_1$.
We can write $Z_1=\sum\{\alpha_j z_j\mid j\in\N\}$,
where $\alpha_j$ are certain real numbers and $z_j=e_j-\left(L\big|_S\right)^{-1}(L(e_j))$, $j\in\N\}$,
form the basis of the kernel $K$ of $L$ discussed in the proof of the Corollary.
Now we choose $A_j$  close to $\alpha_j$ which are algebraically independent
transcendents over $\QQ(M,\hat X_1)$. This is possible, because the algebraic closure of
$\QQ(M,\hat X_1)$ in  $\CC$ is countable.
Then $Z_2=\sum\{A_j z_j\mid j\in\N\}$
is in the kernel $K$,
close to $Z_1$, and its $j$-th components, $j\in\N$, are algebraically independent transcendants
over  $\QQ(M,\hat X_1)$.

The quotient $q_1(\lam)=p_{\tilde M-e_1X_1^{(1)}}(\lam)/D(\lam)$
also has only zeros in the closed unit disk and we
write it
$q_1(\lam)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-d}(\lam-\mu_k)$ with certain $\mu_k$, $|\mu_k|\leq1$.
We choose $s\in[0,1[$ such that $\tilde q_2(\lam)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-d}(\lam-s\mu_k)$ is
close to $q_1(\lam)$, but it has all its zeros in the open unit disk.
Now let $\tilde Y_2=\left(L\big|_S\right)^{-1}(\tilde q_2(\lam)D(\lam)-\lam C_1(\lam))$.
Then $\tilde Y_2\in S=\langle\{e_j\mid j\in \M\}\rangle$
is close to $Y_1$ and $L(\tilde Y_2)=\tilde q_2(\lam)D(\lam)-\lam C_1(\lam)$.
Now the algebraic closure of $\QQ(M,\hat X_1,\{z_j\}_{j\in\N},\{A_j\}_{\in\N})$ in  $\CC$
is countable and therefore there is a vector $Y_2\in S$ close to $\tilde Y_2$ such that its components are algebraically independent
transcendents over that field. If $Y_2$ is sufficiently close to $\tilde Y_2$, then the polynomial
$q_2(\lam)=(L(Y_2)+\lam C_1(\lam))/D(\lam)$ is so close to $\tilde q_2(\lam)$ that its zeros are still in the open unit disk.

Then the vector $y=Y_2+Z_2$ satisfies the three requirements of the statement:
It is close to $X_1^{(1)}$; since $p_{\tilde M-e_1(Y_2+Z_2)}=L(Y_2+Z_2)+\lam C_1\lam=
L(Y_2)+\lam C_1(\lam)=q_2(\lam)D(\lam)$, its zeros are in the closed unit disk and hence $\hat X_1+e_1y\in F$;
finally the components of $y$ are algebraically independent transcendents over $\QQ(M,\hat X_1)$.
Thus Lemma 2 is proved.

We can apply Lemma 2 as well to one of the rows $2,\dots,m$ as to the first row of $M$
-- it is sufficient to exchange the first and this row and the corresponding columns to reach
the exact situation of Lemma 2. This allows us to apply Lemma 2 successively to the row
$2,\dots,m$. This proves

**Corollary 2** Given $X_1\in F$ and positive $\delta$, there exists a $m\times n$-matrix $X_2$ such that
$||X_1-X_2||<\delta$, $X_2\in F$ and the components of the rows $2,\dots,m$ of $X_2$ are
algebraically independent transcendents over $\QQ(M)$.

Now we claim that the gcd $D(\lam)$ of the cofactors $C_j(\lam)$ for the matrix $\lam I -M -N X_2$
has only zeros in the  *open* unit disk. Once this is proved, the proof of the original claim is complete
because, except for the partitioning of the matrix, we are in the case $m=1$.

A priori, $D(\lam)$ is a polynomial in $\lam$ with coefficients in $\QQ(M,\hat X_2)$ because the
$C_j(\lam)$ are (Recall that $\hat X_2$ is the matrix obtained from $X_2$ by replacing the
first row with zeros). The latter are actually in $K[\hat X_2][\lam]$, where $K=\QQ(M)$.
Since $K$ is a field, $K[\hat X_2]$ is a unique factorisation domain because the elements of $\hat X_2$
are algebraically independent transcendents.
We multiply $D(\lam)$ by the lcm
of the denominators of the coefficients (seen as elements of $K(\hat X_2)$), and then divide by
its content (that is the gcd of the coefficients seen as elements of $K[\hat X_2]$). We call the result
$D(\lam)$ again.
Then $D(\lam)\in K[\hat X_2][\lam]$ has content 1 and divides every $C_j(\lam)$ in $K(\hat X_2)[\lam]$
by definition. By [Gauss's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)),
it follows that $D(\lam)$ divides every $C_j(\lam)$ in $K[\hat X_2][\lam]$.

Now, for $j=1,\dots,n$,
$C_j(\lam)$ does not contain any element of the $j$-th column of $\hat X_2$.
Therefore $D(\lam)$ must actually be an element of $K[\lam]$.

Now we use that $E$ is not empty, that is there exists a $m\times n$-matrix $X_0$ such that
$\rho(M-N X_0)<1$.
Let $C_j^{0}$ denote the minors constructed for $\lam I-M+NX_0$ instead of $\lam I-M+NX_2$ where we
obtained the $C_j(\lam)$, $j=1,\dots,n$.
Since $D(\lam)\in K[\lam]$ divides every $C_j(\lam)$ in $K[\hat X_2][\lam]$, we can replace
the elements of $\hat X_2$ by those of $\hat X_0$ in these $n$ relations and obtain that
$D(\lam)$ divides every $C_j^{0}$ in $K(\hat X_0)[\lam]\subset \RR[\lam]$. Hence $D(\lam)$ divides also
the characteristic polynomial $\det(\lam I-M+NX_0)$ (see (\ref{lap})) and hence has only zeros
in the open unit disk as claimed.
As shown above, this completes the proof for general $m$.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I am planning to digest them in the weekends.